# Style SVG loaded to HTML as content tag with CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, font-awesome

I have 3 files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <i class="logo myRed" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.logo:before {
    content: url("logo.svg");
}
.myRed {
    color: #ff2000;
}
```

**logo.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="300" height="100">
    <rect id="logo" width="300" height="100" />
</svg>
```

How to style the SVG that is pointed out in the CSS `content` property? (eg. color, font-size, ...) - like in FontAwesome.

Comment: In case you didn't know, only inline sag can be styled with css. Just keep that in mind.

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao that's not true, you can style any SVG with CSS, it simply does not apply cross documents.

Comment: You need to put the CSS in the SVG file.

Comment: @RobertLongson but this CSS won't have any knowledge of the HTML document, so `.myRed` won't exist for the svg doc (or were you answering a now deleted comment ?)

Comment: @Kaiido Only if you put the definition of .myRed in the SVG file itself.

Comment: @RobertLongson in current code, it is the class of an HTLMIElement which loads the svg through its pseudo element's content css property. So definitely not accessible to the svg.

Comment: @RobertLongson I guess I was not clear but what I meant was CSS applied on the HTML cannot style the contents of the SVG file. But the SVG container itself can be styled. I believe you meant to say the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

CSS `content: url(image.ext)` is similar to loading your image in a `<img>` tag. And loading an image in a `<img>` is under the hood loading it in an isolated document, inaccessible for anyone, and which can't access anything.

FontAwesome doesn't load icons like that, they build font-faces, and then call corresponding characters in the `content` property, e.g something like `"\f07b"`.
So for the browser, FontAwesome icons are just text, and you can style it like any other text.

To style an SVG through CSS, it needs to be in the same document as your stylesheet (or cloned through `<use>`).

---

---

Ok, there is one hack, which may help you, but I can't tell how well it is nor will be supported:
[Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me) [demonstrated](https://gist.github.com/LeaVerou/5198257) that we can (ab)use the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) CSS selector along with the `#elem_id` fragment identifier to show specific nodes of an SVG Element or apply specific rules.

In you svg's `<style>` you can create rules like these ones :

```css
#elem_id_1:target ~ #elem_to_color{
    fill: red;
}
#elem_id_2:target ~ #elem_to_color{
    fill: green;
}
```

Then in your markup, you just need to have some empty elements placed before `#elem_to_color` with corresponding ids.

```
<g id="elem_id_1"></g>
<g id="elem_id_2"></g>
<rect id="elem_to_color"/>
```

Now when you will load your svg as `yourfile.svg#elem_id_1`, the first rule will apply and `#elem_to_color` will be red. If you load it as `yourfile.svg#elem_id_2`, then `#elem_to_color` will be green.

This hack allows to have a single svg file, on which we can externally control the rendered styles.

```css
/* a single file for all colors */

.logo::after {
  content: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2pkolmx0d9pebgl/logo.svg);
}

.logo.green::after {
  content: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2pkolmx0d9pebgl/logo.svg#green);
}

.logo.red::after {
  content: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2pkolmx0d9pebgl/logo.svg#red);
}
```

```html
<!-- logo.svg content
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30">
  <style>
    #green:target ~ #elem_to_color{
      fill: green;
    }
    #red:target ~ #elem_to_color{
      fill: red;
    }
  </style>
  <g id="red"></g>
  <g id="green"></g>
  <rect id="elem_to_color" width="30" height="30"/>
</svg>
-->

<i class="logo"></i>
<i class="logo green"></i>
<i class="logo red"></i>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use these CSS properties:

```
fill:  /* color */
font-size:   /* font-size */
```

It will override the original SVG values, as demonstrated below.

```css
.logo svg {
  fill: #eee;
}
.logo svg text {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.myRed {
color: #ff2000;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo myRed" aria-hidden="true">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect id="logo" width="300" height="100" />
    <text style=" stroke:black; fill:red;" x="30" y="50" font-size="8">Text Here</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: In FontAwesome the Tag <i> is treated as font.
    html: <i class="logo myRed" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    css: as above
    svg: as above
In this case svg file should by loaded by CSS content tag - not directly located in html. Example is on FontAwesome...

Comment: If you have your own SVG, why would you want to use FontAwesome?  Some advantages of inline SVG over font icons:  https://css-tricks.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg/

Answer (score -1):

A more simplified solution would be the following. The first line of css sets the text color (fill), the second line sets the font properties for the text element and the third line targets the rectangle id (logo) to set the fill.

```css
.logo svg {
  fill: #ff0000;
}
.logo svg text {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-face:Arial,Helvetica;
  font-weight:bold
}
#logo {
  fill:#eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo" aria-hidden="true">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect id="logo" width="300" height="100" />
    <text x="30" y="50">Text Here</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```