# CSS SVG background-image as data-uri: is there a way to access ids/classes in that SVG with 'external' CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, sass, data-uri

I have a website / application that uses different color themes.
Those themes are provided in css-custom-properties:

like:

```
:root{
   --main-color: red;
   --lighht-color: gray;
   --dark-color: brown;
    ...
}
```

those are abstracted for flexibility like:

```
:root{
   --main-text-color: var(--dark-color);
   ....
}
```

Now I have check-boxes that should use SVG-Background uri-s like this:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked{
   --check-color: blue;
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 100' style='enable-background:new 0 0 100 100' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E%0A%23check%7B%0Astroke: var(--check-color);%0A%7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3Cpath id='check' style='fill:none;stroke-width:18;stroke-miterlimit:10' d='m24.3 36.8 20.9 29.3 45.7-41.8'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   stroke: red !important;
}
```

you can already see that I tried to change the color of the check-mark from outside the uri-string in several ways without success.

I also tried:

```
:root{
stroke: green;
--check-color: lime;
}
```

and

```
#check{
stroke: pink;
}
```

with no success.

***I did a lot of research and found out that all of those methods will not work, ass the svg in the data-uri is essentially treated as an independent document/dom-sructure form the main document that the is CSS used in...***

I can think of three other ways to work around my problem:

**CSS-masking**: Will likely work, but my actual situation is more complex than the outline I give here and having more than one svg-element to reveal ideally more than one color will be very tricky and complicated.

**SASS**: If there is a (not overly complex) way to read the value of a css-custom property like *root.var(--check-color)* into sass and compile it literally into the CSS (inside the svg-uri), that would be helpfully while not ideal; (The opposite of --my-var: #{$sassVar} so to speak). I couldn't find an opening in to that avenue yet, and with the flexible scoping of css-custom-properties (and them being nested) I guess it will be not easy.

**JavaScript / DOM**: I could go about to inject spans with SVG-Code into the document, but for reasons of accessibility / clear semantics and validity of my html I don't like this at all.
I could also try to read the uri via CSSStyleDeclaration and get the Property, replace the color inside the string and set it back. I guess.
That would probably require to

- check an uncheck a box to get the declaration (not wanting to rely on
  a fixed way of it being coded in css)
- replace a very common string
  like '#000' or 'black' in a more or less complex string. (I wouldn't
  want to put a '$!her-goes-color!$' the svg, as that would break it if
  not replaced...)
- deal with url-encoding and -decoding and
- would have to adjust that script with any style and/or graphic update...

Not ideal at all.

But as most times I'm confident that some of you great and knowledgeable people might have an inspiration or solution for me.
THX!

Comment: I'd suggest moving the svg to the dom, instead of adding it as a background image in css. In this way it is "styleable" using your css variables.

Comment: @Phil: As I mentioned, I'd like to avoid that for accessibility reasons, semantic clarity and html-validity. But in the end I will have to consider it as stated under JavaScript / DOM.
Thanks for sharing you insight.

Comment: I like you're taking accessibility into account. Using the tips shared in this article you should be fine on that part https://css-tricks.com/accessible-svgs/#aa-2-inline-svg

Comment: Does it have to be a data URL? Can't you host an actual file on your server? If so, you could use a :target trick as [exposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045185/style-svg-loaded-to-html-as-content-tag-with-css/46045448#46045448).

Comment: @Kaiido that trick seems not to work in webkit  :-(  - but great find - thanks!

Comment: Definitely works in Safari.

Comment: @Kaiido: My bad, just relied on the probably outdated info on the linked page. I took a closer look now, and as var as I unterstand I would have to prepare for every possible color inside the svg already, that kind of isn't doable.

Comment: @Robert Longson: I don't get your meaning. I have a working data-uri...

Comment: Generate the data url based on the theme using javascript